# I have 3 monitors and one of them goes blank for 2 to 3 seconds every 10 to 15 or so seconds

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have 3 monitors and one of them goes blank for 2 to 3 seconds every 10 or so seconds.

I have changed monitors, cables and graphics cards and I still cannot get 3 monitors "stable" in Xubuntu.

I have no Xorg.conf file and have no idea where to look.  It is driving me batty!

I really want to be able to use my third screen.

I had been using combinations of Display Port and DVI cables in all configurations.  I had not considered VGA, which thanks to @guiverc I did and the usability was resolved.

I do not know why I cannot use multiple display port connected monitors with my set up.  I had literally been scratching my head for months, but on reflection I think I had a bias - I wanted to use DP so never tried analog.

Comment: You've not said what type of cable is used (VGA, DVI, HDMI etc), but HDMI will go dark/blank if quality is below a threshold by design, thus the issue maybe cable or connector related (*if using HDMI for example*)

Comment: It was doing it with Display Port and DVI.  On reading your post I also tried VGA  and it is fine.  Thank you .  I probably wouldn't have tried a third type had you not prompted me.

I cannot see how to mark your answer as the solution, but it was the key to it.

Comment: I wrote a comment only; you can write your own answer (*and refer (or quote) my comment as clue*) and thus gain rep.  You can thus also add whatever other details/actions you did that may benefit others.  Well done for getting there :)